# How to type different data coming from server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an object that is going to have field `products`, this field **will be filled with the response returned by different endpoints which each return a type of product**. something like:

```js
const products = {
  // each of this kind of products comes from endpoint response
  someProduct: {},
  someOtherProduct: {}
  anotherProduct: {}
}
```

All product types share some common properties such as name, description, price. but they also have specific properties that apply only to one type of product. in some cases, I need to traverse all products to render a list of those common properties, but other times I need to render specific data for each type of product.

How do I type this `product` object, if it contains different product types, each of which has different properties and comes from an external data source(server)?

### EDIT 1: Product Type

Each product has an attribute `type`, to identify each product type

### EDIT 2: Selected product type

When I render all products in a list, the user can click on any of them and I store the selected product in a variable... so I can use that selected product to print specific product details... how to type this selected product, if it can be of any type of product?

Comment: you can add a type attribute to indicate which one is it, then check the properties according to the type with an if else statement or ...

Comment: Are You talking about types? I don't get your point... can u answer with a specific example...

Comment: Is there a finite number of product types? You could just type each individual API response, then make the `products` object a Record with a union type of those responses. You'd need type guards (i.e. `const objIsMyProductType(obj: any): obj is MyProductType => return obj.type === 'MyProductType'` to do things while you're traversing . Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you trying to strongly type all possible products, or just define some known ones (and only the base properties for the others)?

Comment: @BrendanBond I have finite product types(six ones), I would appreciate it if you could post a more complete answer so that I can understand the whole context.

Comment: @jsejcksn I think I understand... I want to type all the types of products, which are actually few (6), I also need to type the base of all the products... as I mentioned in the question sometimes I need only the common properties to render a list of products and other times I need the specific properties to paint for example details of a specific product.

Comment: Yeah @joseglego answer is pretty much what I’m telling you to do, thought he uses interfaces rather than types, which are almost interchangeable

Comment: the situation here is that sometimes i will go through all the product types, and i will render it on screen, then user click on some product and I take it as the `productSelected` now as type this selected product if it can be of any of the product types... I think the answer is a combination between what you answered and @joseglego answer

Comment: @BrendanBond could you expand a bit more your answer with type guards in order to get your point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

You can also check one Working Example in CodeSandbox: With an Array and Selected Product, and all the styles: https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-sea-53xh8?file=/src/App.tsx

**ORIGINAL**

You can do something like:

In this case, we are defining a BaseProduct for all the common attributes. We extend this product interface to define each of the other interfaces.

Then, we define a type `Product` which can be any kind of the `Product` interfaces defined previously.

And finally, we can define an Array of `Product` (if your server answer with an array) or an object which can have any string as `key` and `Product` as values.

```js
interface BaseProduct {
  name: string;
  description: string;
  price: number;
  type: string;
}

interface SomeProduct extends BaseProduct {
  genericAttrOne: string;
  genericAttrTwo: string;
}

interface OtherProduct extends BaseProduct {
  anAttributeOne: string;
  anAttributeTwo: string;
}

interface AnotherProduct extends BaseProduct {
  anotherAttributeOne: string;
  anotherAttributeTwo: string;
}

type Product = SomeProduct | OtherProduct | AnotherProduct;

const productsAsArray: Product[] = [];
const productsAsObject: { [key: string]: Product }: {};
```

Comment: the situation here is that sometimes I will go through all the product types(productsAsArray in your answer), and I will render it, then user click on some product and I take it as the `productSelected`. how should I type this productSelected if it can be of any type of product? and for this selectedProduct I will access product-specific properties...

Comment: In that case: your `selectedProduct` will be type `Product`, now about the iteration and product-specific properties you will need extra conditionals or different Components for each of them.

Comment: @CristianFlórez I just updated with one codesandbox link so, you can check how to do it :)

Comment: in your example, especifically in `ProductDetail` file, `SomeDetails`, `OtherDetails` and `AnotherDetails` is throwing type errors... `Property 'anotherAttributeTwo' does not exist on type 'Product'.` this error happend in every specific Product component

Comment: Yep, I noticed that (I already edited the sandbox), you can use the specific type for each detail when you want to focus on each type. You can check the sandbox now it has SomeDetails (with `Product`)  as Prop and gives the error. But also, we have SomeDetailsTwo (with `SomeProduct`) and work like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example for strongly typing the response that you described:

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=80&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/PTAEGUBcEMCdNAdwJaQBanQU1AI2gM44AOsA9gCYCuAxpADSgVYBmyAdhwOaZo41kAtoLLtQpMsSzxkWAgChIATymgACuWp0APPNCgAKqCwAPSFnYUCoApFjdQAXht3u9PeqegASlgGwKbXYsADdpRmCw2AA+d2ivNVAAMlAAbw9lKQAuQwBuD3ZoQSwc23t2Lnz9ZgIae2JIZFFS1wqq8XsaEtB2KkFcaXyAX3z5EEM+MWY2YONoGgwJLUgAcmsCKRpkNhpMFRxoSw7JaUa5RX2IISwNSloEZ1vl7TXrlcZ0-QJrgDVoABsqFgAIwtcqVDzfYp-QFYABMOV6-UG8iG0VG4wAYmRYMYokpjssLqoAILsMjYWBPe4JTT3F6HCl8WDvNIeRmUmFA0EucHtDnMrnwxF9AawYbo+RjMAGSagQgEZBcMTYQTy-7-TBkY5SGRyUAceViMi4ABWfgQZBYoAA1uTEGIlvcFJkcABpe3sal0azOT42a45cDXb2Qfnkyk5MlM6Sh9rjLCQGgAOlTqIxYAAwrAsNBzPK9qoWDjbZ7Cc7QABqI0ErgWaTIXZOuhIVAYATCUQ606yF2XEka0O+0AesgOofJNKgADaNqwSjB3AAujlQ6ARlLmDR-nB+KJbOWfVHB3SfaNm5ACMmoVhk4ViqBxmQbfIL1eBdI70UcE+X6-T5e17XMmrqPmAABEN7gf+dw+kBxTwVgQrAmBoDPjByxXjeyYfrAyGoRIurKEwZByOwKwIKYyC2FKb44RGzIgZc4zgbh0F0bhiH4eMhGnASFCkQQ5GUSY1GQBhzr0TGsBSZyALcqh6HSqAA6atJh6Xq2Gpoew-wEmg0BhLwe6dl2vF6godGCEotjSEooZfsUuSKX+ykAHJwOQKAVAWF6FiUUqgaO44AV4wVegBBCzvOVojp6Q5LvkoFkvZoXOOFa4AD7qABowsFQ7B0E0UxkMGxToNwADqbYkmuAAUF5RuwqWwZAACUOQhGQyAUGy+gJiYxD-I2qB6aABmWP8-CEPqxa4naY6OpFoBUIqPmHPKBBEDIoiMIcvXYKAOYsNIFhdKAAAGxAXR4AjsAexBeH5hBxYtcaQigSYYA1TFSG1fX6KANAzaArzFCsOT+oD4i-T+EFQR40PEI5cNoS+0P6MjN7cWA6EYzDuE46AACisDkLAq7kER-GCcJxiiTR+O4Dm0A2u0+hDIjQMgysuEQwDSOw6hrEMdI0H48j96o3jGNY788kgqhpPk5TJzwDTZEUfTYlc5jsmCgrKG-rreAs2zXOc9D4yGod0zQFQ-wIMDRArS7h1wFwfQWAgV0ARdoB1YgaCNhg1EuMg2kpaGbVc3bDuQJDJsXij7OA8zubm9Dlvrqi8hAA)

```ts
// Start with the base product, defining the common properties
type Product<
  T extends string = string,
  P = Record<never, never>,
> = P & {
  type: T;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  price: number;
};

// Then define each product's specific type and properties
type SomeProduct = Product<'some', {
  someValue1: string;
  someValue2: number;
}>;

// For every product
type AnotherProduct = Product<'another', {
  anotherValue1: string;
  anotherValue2: number;
}>;

// Then assign them all to properties in an object of known products
type KnownProducts = {
  some: SomeProduct;
  another: AnotherProduct;
  // etc...
};

// Create a type for known products + any generic product with common properties
type AllProducts = KnownProducts & { [key: string]: Product };

declare const products: AllProducts;

products.some.name // ok
products.another.name // ok

products.some.type // "some"
products.some.someValue1 // ok
products.some.anotherValue1 // property doesn't exist

products.another.type // "another"
products.another.someValue1 // property doesn't exist
products.another.anotherValue1 // ok

// All other products will only have the commoon properties
products.mysteryProduct.name; // ok


// Narrowing a product type:

type KnownProduct = KnownProducts[keyof KnownProducts];
type AnyProduct = KnownProduct | Product;

function doSomethingWithAProduct (product: AnyProduct): void {
  // explicitly handle cases for known products using an assertion, and the reference `p`
  const p = product as KnownProduct;
  switch (p.type) {
    case 'some': {
      p.type // "some"
      p.name // ok
      p.someValue1 // ok
      p.anotherValue1 // Error: Property doesn't exist
      break;
    }
    case 'another': {
      p.type // "another"
      p.name // ok
      p.someValue1 // Error: Property doesn't exist
      p.anotherValue1 // ok
      break;
    }
    // in the default case use the argument `product` (which is still AnyProduct)
    default: {
      product.name;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the situation here is that sometimes I will go through all the product types(Products in your answer), and I will render it, then user click on some product and I take it as the `productSelected`. how should I type this `productSelected` if it can be of any type of product? and for this selectedProduct I will access product-specific properties...

Comment: 1. Now you've asked a different question than your original question. 2. Does the value of each product's `type` property match the name of its key in the products object?

Comment: Yes, I post another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70208956/how-typing-a-selected-object-type-from-a-list-of-different-objects) related to this one...  I'd appreciate it if you could respond there to get a little more context....

Comment: I have updated my answer to address your additional requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your subsequent comments to the two (very good) answers, in which you ask about typing an undetermined product type at runtime (i.e. when a user selects a product) you need to use [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html):

```
// here’s the type guard for one type, you’ll need one for all six; we’re checking against your `type` property but it could be anything
const isMyProductType = (obj: any): obj is MyProductType => obj.type === “myProductType”;

const onClick = (selectedProduct) => {
  if (isMyProductType(selectedProduct)) {
    // TS now will treat selectedProduct as an object of MyProductType
    // do stuff 
  } else if (/* another type guard etc … */) {
    // etc
  }
}
```