# How typing a selected object from a list of different objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an object that is going to have field products, this field will be filled with the response returned by different endpoints which each return a type of product. something like:

```js
const products = {
  // each of this kind of products comes from endpoint response
  someProduct: {},
  someOtherProduct: {}
  anotherProduct: {}
}
```

I Can type all product types like this, according this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70208520/how-to-type-different-data-coming-from-server/70208677?noredirect=1#comment124111039_70208677):

```js
interface BaseProduct {
  name: string;
  description: string;
  price: number;
  type: string;
}

interface SomeProduct extends BaseProduct {
  genericAttrOne: string;
  genericAttrTwo: string;
}

interface OtherProduct extends BaseProduct {
  anAttributeOne: string;
  anAttributeTwo: string;
}

interface AnotherProduct extends BaseProduct {
  anotherAttributeOne: string;
  anotherAttributeTwo: string;
}

type Product = SomeProduct | OtherProduct | AnotherProduct;

const productsAsArray: Product[] = [];
```

the situation here is that sometimes I will go through all the product types(productsAsArray), and I will render it, then user click on some product and I take it as the `productSelected`. how should I type this `productSelected` if it can be of any type of product? and for this `selectedProduct` I will access product-specific properties...

Comment: Why are you using 3 different types if their signature is the same?

Comment: Is just for illustrative purpose every product has a common properties but every product type has specific properties...

Answer (score 1):

Use [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions)
 to help you narrow your type down.

Here is an example:

```js
interface Base {
  type: string;
  baseProp: string;
}

interface T1 extends Base {
  type: "t1";
  t1prop: string;
}

interface T2 extends Base {
  type: "t2";
  t2prop: string;
}

interface T3 extends Base {
  type: "t3";
  t3prop: string;
}

type union = T1 | T2 | T3;

function list(arr: union[]) {
  const randomArrItem = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
  specificMethod(randomArrItem);
}

function specificMethod(t: union) {
  const { type } = t;
  switch (type) {
    case "t1":
      console.log(t.t1prop);
      // console.log(t.t2prop); // error: Property 't2prop' does not exist on type 'T1'. Did you mean 't1prop'?(2551)
      break;
    case "t2":
      console.log(t.t2prop);
      break;
    case "t3":
      console.log(t.t3prop);
      break;
    default:
      throw new Error("wrong type");
  }
}
```

See TS Playground: https://tsplay.dev/wj4obm

Comment: This question is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/70208520/438273, and in that question, the OP states that there might also be unknown products whose `type` value is `string`.

Answer (score 0):

Since they have the same signature, add a new property `type` that is an enum.

The reason to use an enum is that you can check it with an if or switch case.

```
const enum ProductType {
  one = "ONE",
  two= "TWO",
  three= "THREE",
}

interface BaseProduct {
  name: string;
  description: string;
  price: number;
}

type ProductOne = BaseProduct & {
  type: ProductType.one,
  prop1: string,
  prop2: string
}

type ProductTwo = BaseProduct & {
  type: ProductType.two,
  prop1: string,
  prop2: string
}

type ProductThree = BaseProduct & {
  type: ProductType.three,
  prop1: string,
  prop2: string
}

type Product = ProductOne | ProductTwo | ProductThree ;

function handleProductSwitch(product: Product){
  switch(product.type){
    case ProductType.one:
      // handle ProductOne
    case ProductType.two:
      // handle ProductTwo
    case ProductType.three:
      // handle ProductThree
    case default:
  }
}

function handleProductIf(product: Product){
  if(product.type === ProductType.one) productOneHandler(product);
  if(product.type === ProductType.two) productTwoHandler(product);
  if(product.type === ProductType.three) productThreeHandler(product);
}
```